# How I can find out what is the latest xdebug version in my php script that installs xdebug?

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

I made a script that installs xdebug using php itself:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 *  Xdebug setup Script - php version
 *  Copyright (C) 2023  Dimitrios Desyllas
 *
 *  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

// Besause I want the script to be runnable at any circumstance I avoid https (mostly on legacy systems)
define(DOWNLOAD_URL,"http://pecl.php.net/get/xdebug");
define(PHP_VER,PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.'.'.PHP_MINOR_VERSION);

$final_url=DOWNLOAD_URL;

// Use old array style for backwards compartibility
$xdebug_version_per_php_ver = array(
    "7.1"=>"2.9.8",
    "7.0"=>"2.7.2",
    "5.6"=>"2.5.5",
    "5.5"=>"2.5.5",
    "5.4"=>"2.4.1",
    "5.3"=>"2.2.6",
);


$xdebug_version = getenv("XDEBUG_VERSION");
if(empty($xdebug_version)){
    $xdebug_version="";
}
$xdebug_version = trim($xdebug_version);

// We need to ignore any compartibility check if php defined is the one we specify.
if((!empty($xdebug_version) && $xdebug_version!="latest")){
    $final_url.="-".$xdebug_version.".tgz";
} elseif(isset($xdebug_version_per_php_ver[PHP_VER])) { // Upon latest we check compartible versions
    $final_url.="-".$xdebug_version_per_php_ver[PHP_VER].".tgz";
} else {
    exec("pecl install xdebug",$v,$status_code);
    exit($status_code);
}

if(!@copy($final_url,'/tmp/xdebug.tgz')){
    $errors= error_get_last();
    fprintf(STDERR,$errors['message']);
    exit(1);
}

if ( !file_exists( '/tmp/xdebug' ) || !is_dir( '/tmp/xdebug') ) {
    mkdir('/tmp/xdebug'); 
}

echo "Extracting downloaded file /tmp/xdebug.tgz";
exec("tar -xv -C /tmp/xdebug -f /tmp/xdebug.tgz | grep xdebug | head -1 | cut -f1 -d\"/\"",$dirname);
$dirname = trim(implode($dirname)); // I EXPECT 1 WORD OUTPUT

if(!file_exists('/tmp/xdebug/'.$dirname)){
    fprintf(STDERR,"FILE NOT EXTRACTED".PHP_EOL);
    exit(1);
}

chdir('/tmp/xdebug/'.$dirname);
exec("ls -l",$output);
print_r($output);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pd=popen('phpize;./configure --enable-xdebug&&make&&make install','r');
fpassthru($pd);
pclose($pd);

unlink('/tmp/xdebug');
```

My goal is to install the appropriate xdebug even upon legacy and obsolete php versions (For legacy systems).

But in the line I use pecl:

```
} else {
    exec("pecl install xdebug",$v,$status_code);
    exit($status_code);
}
```

And I want instead somehow to scrape/detect the latest *stable* version of xdebug. Using the url "https://pecl.php.net/get/xdebug" may not download the latest stable version of xdebug.

Is there a way to know the latest **stable** version for each php version. Maintaining a map of the latest is too much of a hastle for long term usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is easy. The Pecl has an api where by visiting the url:

```
https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/xdebug/stable.txt
```

You can get the latest version number. It is as easy as:

```
$xdebug_version=file_get_contents("https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/xdebug/stable.txt");
```

At your code. If you want per php version seem more like you'll need to maintain a map or scrape it from xdebug website.

Comment: How is that giving you the latest stable version **by PHP version**? https://xdebug.org/docs/compat#versions

Comment: I want if latest php to install the latest xdebug without the need to maintain a list of compartible versions. The list in the script is for legacy versions.

Comment: In your original question you've asked: "Is there a way to know the latest stable version **for each php version**.", but your answer only provides the latest stable version **without** taking the php version into account. You should probably either edit the question or the answer so they match. ;)

Comment: There is some code on https://xdebug.org/wizard src https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.org/blob/master/src/XdebugVersion.php that has this info, but is currently not exposed as an API. I intend to submit a PR when time permits.